# dc.js Scatter Chart with dot color based on counts

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am having a hard time trying to accomplish something simple.
I need to display a XY scatter plot in DC js charts. However, I may have several points with the same XY values. In this case, the color of a XY point must change according to a function that receives as input the number of repetitions.

Ex:

X  -   Y

1  -  9

1  -  9

1  -  9

1  -  4

2  -  10

3  -  5

1  -  4

Point 1  -  9 appears 3 times...  Red Color

Is it possible to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use the [colorAccessor](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colorAccessor__anchor) to assign colors based on the value. (By default it is colored based on the series.)

Additionally, you'll probably want to specify the color scale so that you have control about the value to color mapping. Below we map 0-4 to yellow, blue, purple, red, orange.

```
scatterPlot
  .colorAccessor(function(kv) { return kv.value; })
  .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(5)).range(['yellow', 'blue', 'purple', 'red', 'orange']))
```

Comment: Just to be sure...  kv.value is the number of times a XY point appears, correct?  I do not need to calculate it before plotting the chart, right?

Comment: That's right, by default crossfilter will [reduce by count](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduceCount), and since you are using the x and y coordinates as your key, it will count the number of points at each location.

Comment: always good to receive an answer from the person who develope the library :-)